# Featherjs Serverside Upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, feathersjs

Does anyone have any examples of how I can handle the files that are sent to featherjs?

I have the following client side completely separate from featherjs but haven't trouble actually accessing said files in my service.

```
var req = request.post('http://uploadhost/upload').set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+this.props.authtoken);

this.state.files.forEach(file => {
    req.attach(file.name, file);
});
req.end(this.callback);
```

Comment: Please show your server code attempt. I imagine the files are in the response object. FeatherJS just extends express, so it should be on the response.

Comment: @Rafael I don't know what you mean. I don't have a server code concept. I generate a service with `feathers generate service` and when I `console.log(data, params)` for the `create` function there is no way to access to files

Answer (score 0):

FeathersJS just extends express. You need to add a multipart parser, like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), if you are decoding form data (which looks like you are).

```
const multer = require('multer');
const multipartMiddleware = multer();

// Upload Service with multipart support
app.use('/uploads',

    // multer parses the file named 'uri'.
    // Without extra params the data is
    // temporarely kept in memory
    multipartMiddleware.single('uri'),

    // another middleware, this time to
    // transfer the received file to feathers
    function(req,res,next){
        req.feathers.file = req.file;
        next();
    },
    blobService({Model: blobStorage})
);
```

Ultimately, feathers uses [their blob service](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-blob) to create files.

```
const blobService = require('feathers-blob');
const blobStorage = fs(__dirname + '/uploads');
```

[Read More](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/advanced/file-uploading.html)

I hope this helps clarify my comment.